# Reactive approach/types in Micronaut for RESTful APIs

Tags: java, reactive-programming, micronaut

I'm not quite clear about these reactive types when dealing with RESTful APIs.

My understanding is that **non-reactive** request/responses are made of either simple POJO types or the `String` type. On the other hand, **reactive** request/responses –for instance, if using RxJava `2.x`- are made of `Simple<T>` or `Flowable<T>`.

But then how to approach the reactive model/way when using the `HttpRequest<T>` / `HttpResponse<T>` "wrapper" types? I've always like to express the requests/responses with those and **not any other type(s)** because there are plenty of times one might need to express different HTTP responses types (among other things), for instance:

```
@Get(value = "/{id}", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON])
fun getById(id: String): HttpResponse<Issue> {
  //logger.info { "${request.method} ${request.path}" }
  return service.findById(UUID.fromString(id))
    .map { HttpResponse.ok(it) }
    .orElseGet { HttpResponse.notFound() }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. What would be the correct way to implement a reactive RESTful API in Micronaut using the `HttpRequest<T>` / `HttpResponse<T>` "wrapper" types?
2. Is there a way to verify any difference(s) when using the non-reactive approach and the reactive one?

Comment: You have asked 2 fundamentally separate questions.  You should probably break those into separate SO posts.

Answer (score -1):

You can return something like `Flowable<HttpResponse<T>>`.